# Understanding an example on calculating eigenvalues and eigenvectors.

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations

The example is given below:

> [image]

But I do not understand the example given after the word in particular, why $\operatorname{spec}(\alpha) = \varnothing$? where $\operatorname{spec}(\alpha)$ is the set of all eigenvalues of $\alpha$ and $\sigma_{c}: v \rightarrow cv$ for $c \in F.$

Comment: What exactly is the confusion here? Your picture explains to you "To see this ..." Which sentence/phrase do you not understand?

Answer (score 1):

In the picture that you post is the explanation. Let me make it clearer. Suppose $\operatorname{spec}(\alpha)\neq\varnothing$, then there is some $c$ in $\operatorname{spec}(\alpha)$. Let's say $\alpha(v)=cv$ for some non-zero vector $v$. Now, 
$$\alpha^2(v)=\alpha(\alpha(v))=\alpha(cv)=c\alpha(v)=c^2v$$
and since $\alpha^2=-\sigma_1$ it follows that $-1v=c^2v$. Rearranging this gives us $(c^2+1)v=0_V$. But $v\neq 0_V$, so $c^2+1=0$, which is impossible.

Comment: $spec (\alpha)$ contain scalars and not vectors

Comment: how is what you explained applied to the given $2 \times 1$ matrix?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. Is already corrected. The argument works any way.

Comment: I do not fully understand your question. But the example in the image is clear, it is a anti-clockwise rotation of $90^\circ$ doing in the plane. Intuitively, this transformation should not have eigenvectors (nor eigenvalues, of course).

Comment: why it should not have eigenvectors nor eigenvalues?